# Quadratic function in real space is a product of two linear functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:V\to \mathbb{R}$ quadratic function. Show that $f$ is  product of two linear functions if and only if its rank $\leq 2$. And if rank is $2$ show that signature of $f$ is $0$.

**Remark:** I know that this problem is quite a famous one. But please do not duplicate it and let me show what I've done.

**My approach:** $\Rightarrow$ By definition $f:V\to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x)=\varphi(x,x)$ where $\varphi$ is symmetric bilinear form. We know that there is a basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ for $V$ where matrix of $\varphi$ is diagonal with $\pm 1, 0$ on it. Let's denote this matrix by $F$ and then $f(x)=X^tFX$, where $X$ is a column of coordinates of $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

Suppose $f$ is a product of two linear functions $a,b:V\to \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $f(x)=a(x)b(x)$. Then we know that $$a(x)=X^tA \ \text{and} \ b(x)=BX$$ where $A=\begin{bmatrix}
a(e_1)   \\
\vdots \\
a(e_n)  
\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}
b(e_1) \dots b(e_n)   \\  
\end{bmatrix}$. Then $f(x)=a(x)b(x)$ can be written in matrix form, i.e. $$X^tFX=X^tABX \ \Leftrightarrow X^t(F-AB)X=0$$

But since the last equation holds for all columns $X$ it follows that $F-AB$ is skew-symmetric matrix (I discussed it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3550360/some-questions-about-quadratic-forms)). Then I stuck and don't know what to do.

Would be very grateful if someone will show how to solve this problem, please.

Comment: You seem to be going through a book or set of notes. What book?

Comment: @WillJagy, I am using lecture notes in Russian "Linear algebra and geometry"by Prof. T.E.Panov (Moscow State University). But I am solving the problems from the book which is also in Russian. I am learning theory and solving problems I guess it should help to improve my background in linear algebra.

Comment: @WillJagy, could you help with my questions, please? I will appreciate your help!

Comment: Well, if $f=f_1f_2$ with $f_1,f_2$ linear, then we have three cases: We could have $f_1=f_2=0$. Then $f=0$ has rank $0$. If $f_1=rf_2$ are non-zero, then $f=rf_1^2$. Making the change of variable $x=f_1$ we get that $f=rx^2$ has rank $1$. If $f_1,f_2$ are linearly independent, then making the change of variable $z=f_1$ and $w=f_2$ we get $f=zw$. Making the change of variable $z=x+y,w=x-y$ we get $f=x^2-y^2$. So $f$ has rank $2$.

Comment: @lepidon, how did you get three cases? Can you explain it in a separate answer, please? I will appreciate it!! Just want to know the details.

Comment: They are all possible things that can happen, either $f_1=f_2=0$, or $f_1,f_2$ are linearly dependent but not zero, or $f_1,f_2$ are linearly independent.

Comment: By the way, the other direction is not true (over $\mathbb{R}$). The form $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ has rank $2$, but it is not a product of two linear forms. Are the coefficients $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @lepidon, but what about myvapproach which i showed above? Is it correct somehow?

Comment: Well, I think there are no errors in what you wrote, but it doesn't finishes. The crucial idea is to use $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ ($f_1,f_2$ in my notation) for a change of variable. Whether one will need $0,1$ or $2$ independent variables depends on the cases that I wrote above.

Comment: Let me think and digest what you wrote. Anyway i am thankful for your help!

Comment: Let me tell you how the other direction goes with complex coefficients. If $f=ax^2+by^2$, where $a,b\in\{0,\pm1\}$, then we look at similar cases as above. If $a=b=0$, then $f=0$. If $b=0\neq a$, then $f=ax^2$ is a product of the linear forms $ax$ and $x$. If $a,b\neq0$, then $f=(\sqrt{a}x+\sqrt{b}iy)(\sqrt{a}x-\sqrt{b}iy)$.

Comment: Your solution is really nice. I did not think in this way at all. But small remark. So you splitted the solution into 3 cases. In the first you claimed that both of them are zero. But i guess you meant that at least one of them is zero. Right? Because in the second and rhird case you have considered non zero functions.

Comment: Btw, your change of variable should be nondegenerate, right?

Comment: ZFR, I may have mentioned this before, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr  There is a nice algorithm  for taking symmetric real $H$ and constructing nonsingular $P,$ so that $P^T HP = D$ is diagonal. Sylvester says the rank of $D$ is the same as rank of $H.$ If opposite signs, $m L_1^2 - n L_2^2 $ with $L_j$ linear forms factors over the reals as $(\sqrt m L_1 + \sqrt n L_2) \cdot ().  $ If same sign, still factors over complexes, just as $x^2 + y^2 = (x+iy)(x-iy)$